# Why Django signals doesn't work for me? (updated INSTALLED_APPS as it should be.)

Tags: python, django, signals, profile

I want to have a profile created after a user is registered to the app. So I put the Django signals in my app as it is told in Corey Schafer's tutorial part 8. But It seems I have some weird and hidden problems in the project. Because it literally doesn't work, doesn't create a profile based on a newly registered user. To solve this, I added a line to my **init**.py file and updated the INSTALLED_APPS section in settings.py as explained in other questions at StackOverflow. But none of them has made a change.

So, what is my missing point? How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance, for your time and effort!

```
auctions/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from PIL import Image


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/profile_default.jpg', upload_to = 'profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile' 

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.img.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(size)
            img.save(self.img.path)
```

```
auctions/signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile



@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

```
auctions/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AuctionsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'auctions'
    def ready(self):
        import auctions.signals
```

Comment: how does your `__init__.py` file in the `auctions` app looks like?

Comment: Are you listening to signals on the correct `User` model? In your signals you are using the model from `django.contrib.auth` but in your models you have a custom user model

Comment: @IainShelvington: good point! He is listening to the `User` model of `django.contrib.auth`, not of `auctions`.

Comment: Thank you Willem Van Onsem and Iain Shelvington! I'm new here in StackOverFlow and you helped me very quickly, that is really nice of you.  As you said, I checked signals.py and changed it. Now it works well. Thank you both again!